# C# - Binary search a (sorted) Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, search

I have a file of records, sorted alphabetically:

- Andrew d432
- Ben x127
- ...
- ...
- Zac b332

The first field is a person name, the second field is some id. Once I read the file, I do not need to make any changes to the data.

I want to treat each record as a Key-Value pair, where the person name is the Key. I don't know which class to use in order to access a record (as fast as possible). `Dictionary` does not has a binary search. On the other hand, as I understand, `SortedList` and `SortedDictionary` should be used only when I need to insert/remove data.

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm talking about simply accessing a record, like:

```
x = MyDic[Zac]
```

Comment: Dictionary will have constant time access because it will use the hash of the key as an index to the value.  There's no need for a binary search assuming you want an exact match lookup.

Comment: confused. you have a dictionary which (should) provide you with O(1) access to any key/value you want (if it exists). what exactly did you want to search on?

Comment: Side-note: what if your file contains a line `George Bernard Shaw 1234`. Do you recognize that the name consists of three "names"?

Comment: If your keys are all unique - then `Dictionary<string, string>` is suitable data structure in your case, but you don't need binary search at all. If your keys are not unique, then probably you need `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where for each unique key you will store list of ids - and again you don't need binary search, dictionary will search for constant time.

Comment: @matiaselgart: O(1) doesn't mean that it is fast as binary search, to my understanding.

Comment: @Bohoo http://bigocheatsheet.com/. i should have clarified my statement in that for a dictionary, O(1) is the _Average Case_.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: Why using a dictionary is suitable? The dictionary doesn't "know" that it is sorted, so getting a record should be slower compared to binary search of a `List`, for example.

Comment: When you use a Dictionary, once you have the Key value you can get the value directly e.g. the command MyDictionary["Zac"] should return "b332", in your case. What kind of search exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Bohoo dictionary will be faster in most cases than binary search over sorted array (if size of array is relatively large) since it takes O(1) instead of O(log(n)).

Comment: @jambonick: Please see my edit

Comment: @Bohoo, maybe `x = MyDic["Zac"]` (`Dictionary<string,string>`) ?

Comment: Having sorted data may be useful somehow (check `SortedDictionary`), but in general I'd ignore that fact and just load all data into normal `Dictionary<string,string>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What no one has stated is *why* dictionaries are O(1) and *why* it IS faster than a binary search. One side point is that *dictionaries are not sorted by the key*.  The whole point of a dictionary is to go to the *exact** (for all practical purposes) location of the item that is referenced by the key value.  It does not "search" for the item - it knows the *exact* location of the item you want.

So a binary search would be pointless on a hash-based dictionary because there is no need to "search" for an item when the collection already knows exactly where it is.

<sub>*This isn't completely true in the case of hash collisions, but the *principle* of the dictionary is to get the item directly, and any additional lookups are an implementation detail and should be rare.</sub>

> On the other hand, as I understand, `SortedList` and `SortedDictionary` should be used only when I need to insert/remove data.

They should be used when you want the data *automatically* sorted when adding or removing data.  Note that `SortedDictionary` loses the performance gain of a "normal" dictionary because it now has to search for the location using the key value.  It's primary use is to allow you to iterate over the keys in order.

If you have a unique key value per item, don't need to iterate the items in any particular order, and want the fastest "get" performance, then `Dictionary` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

*In general* dictionary lookup will be faster than binary search of a collection. There are two specific cases when that's not true:

1. If the list is small (fewer than 15 (possibly as low as 10) items, in my tests), then the overhead of computing a hash code and going through the dictionary lookup will be slower than binary search on an array. But beyond 15 items, dictionary lookup beats binary search, hands down.
2. If there are many hash collisions (due either to a bad hash function or a dictionary with a high load factor), then dictionary lookup slows down. If it's really bad, then binary search could potentially beat dictionary lookup.

In 15 years working with .NET dictionaries holding all kinds of data, I've never seen #2 be a problem when using the standard `String.GetHashCode()` method with real world data. The only time I've run into trouble is when I created a bad `GetHashCode()` method.

Comment: Even #1 seems highly unlikely as the only time you'd perform one pass in a binary search if when the item is in the exact middle of the collection.  Otherwise, I'd expect the cost of multiple searches to be higher then the cost of hash code computation.

Comment: @DStanley: In my tests (this was five or more years ago), binary search was faster overall when the size was 8 or less. After 8, dictionary began to pull ahead and was hands-down faster at 15. This was the average time across a million searches, including some percentage of searches for things that weren't in the collection. My conclusion was that dictionary overhead (computing hash code and finding the bucket) was approximately equal to the cost of 3 or 4 iterations of the binary search loop.